# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x25418e000) to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the titled error in the query Stored in aWords: String after I updated my Mac OS and Xcode from 7 to 11.1 and Swift 2.2 to Swift 4:
Previously the code was running perfectly in swift 2.2 but now this query is giving an error and is not getting fixed.
The query access database getting country and city name and then Latitude and longitude.

```swift
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        if searchController.searchBar.text == ""
        {
            return
        }
        self.openDatabase()
        filteredResults.removeAllObjects()
        if let wordsResultSet = database.executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM citiesTable,country  WHERE country.country_id = 
    citiesTable.country_id and cityName LIKE '\
    (searchController.searchBar.text!)%' LIMIT 50", withArgumentsIn: nil)

        {
            while wordsResultSet.next()
            {
        let aWord: String =  (wordsResultSet["cityName"] as! String) + " , 
" + (wordsResultSet["name"] as! String) +  "-$-" +
            (wordsResultSet["latitude"] as! String) + "-$-" +  
(wordsResultSet["longitude"] as! String)

                filteredResults.add(aWord)
            }
        } else {
            print("select failed: \(String(describing: database.lastErrorMessage()))")
        }

        database.close()
        self.tableVw.reloadData()

    }
```

The Error Message in Code
[image]
The previous working output of the code in swift 2.2  was:

[image: this]

Comment: Alexender if u want i can mail the whole view controller

Comment: The reason for you to spend some time to format your code here is because it makes it easier to read for us which will increase the chance that you get help with your question.

Comment: Joakim Danielson i have formatted the code a little bit. Check if it helps

Comment: `wordsResultSet` is obviously `[String:Any]`. That's what the error message says. Actually the solution is already in the same line where the error occurs.

Comment: I cannot see the error message though

Comment: Vadian Please make it clearer ?

Comment: @Olympiloutre The title shows the error and (let aWords: String) this line shows the error which has the query

Comment: It looks like you need to do the same `as! String` there as well

Comment: You have to **cast** `wordsResultSet["latitude"]` to the actual type like `as! String` in the same line, but it could be also Double.

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x25418e000) to 'NSString'  i get this error while typing in search field

Comment: @vadian How? would i declare it double as well

Comment: That's very basic stuff. As I assumed latitude and longitude are `Double` which the error clearly confirms. Replace `as! String` with `as! Double`.

Comment: @vadian after doing that i get this error, The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: Then please do what the compiler suggests.

Comment: @vadian please can u write the correct syntax for aWord declaration,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error #1

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x25418e000) to 'NSString'

**Solution:**

Cast latitude and longitude to `Double`

---

Error #2

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

**Solution:**

Assign the dictionary values to variables and then concatenate the string with Sting Interpolation

---

```
let city = wordsResultSet["cityName"] as! String
let name = wordsResultSet["name"] as! String
let latitude = wordsResultSet["latitude"] as! Double
let longitude = wordsResultSet["longitude"] as! Double

let aWord = "\(city) , \(name)-$-\(latitude)-$-\(longitude)"
```

Comment: Thank u so much, that was what i wanted

Comment: You're welcome. Please learn to understand those error messages. They are very descriptive.

Comment: sure i will inshaAllah